# How do you access elements from client-side xml document using Javascript?

Tags: xml

I have a local (client-side) xml file (books.xml) stored in the same folder as my js and html code. I want to be able to access various elements from the xml and ideally store them as strings. I have looked around, but everyone seems to be recommending XMLHttpRequest, but that relies on the use of a server stored xml file. I have attached the xml file. Please help!

XML File: http://pastebin.com/AkeG6q6e

Comment: So which browsers do you target? Firefox should let you use XMLHttpRequest on a local file. For Chrome you would need to start it with some command line option lowering the security settings. For IE I think it usually disables script in locally loaded files completely, once you allow that you should be able to use XMLHttpRequest or `new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0')` or directly `var doc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0'); doc.load('file.xml');`.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers implement lots of security restrictions for accessing local files. Some browsers will allow you to read files which are in the same directory as the HTML document (or a subdirectory of it) in which case: **Use XMLHttpRequest**.

Otherwise, you're out of luck. Web browsers are designed to operate on the WWW, not on local files, and security restrictions are pretty strong.